PayPay payment option is not visible in express checkout in react native expo app
I have developed a shopping website with PayPal payment integration, payment method is fully functional, But when I try to open the same through a react native expo app (via WebView) only the PayPal payment option is not visible while other payment options are visible in express checkout.
In terms of element usage PayPal option is in iframe element while others payment options are in div element.
According to React Native Expo's WebView documentation, it supports iframes.
Should the visibility of the PayPal payment option be affected because of the iframe?
since there is no react native expo specific code changes are made, it should not impact visibility of PayPal payment option on app as the app uses the same website code. 
 
Kindly revert with a solution or suggestion
I find only differences in iframe and div element.

Unclear how you integrated or are attempting to display a PayPal payment method. JS SDK buttons can render in a webview but they will not be functional unless something like braintree/popup-bridge-android or braintree/popup-bridge-ios is used

On checkOut button  click of our website we navigating on shopify checkout page when all payment option are displayed ,

Shopify may have code to prevent the button from rendering when the page is rendered in an iframe, since it won't work unless your native app has a popup bridge.

we are using checkout from shopify website and  all the express checkout payments option comes from shopify, we  don’t have access to control shopify UI. We have not done any separate react native expo coding for app. We are just rendering the our website url in a webView of react native expo.

Exactly.....and Shopify is apparently (correctly) refusing to render the PayPal button as part of that checkout, since IT WILL NOT WORK IN A WEBVIEW. If you want the PayPal checkout to work in a webview, you need to use a popup bridge, though there is no way Shopify would know you are using a popup bridge. In other words, what you are trying to do likely cannot be done--not with Shopify anyway, not unless you hear otherwise from Shopify
